# nginx and unicorn not working

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I set nginx and unicorn on ubuntu14.04 to access my rails app!

but, I access my domain, chrome responsed 'connection refused'

I don't know why...

How can I resolve this problem?

There is my nginx.conf and unicorn file.

【nginx.conf】

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##
    
    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

【myapp-unicorn】（/etc/nginx/site-enabled/myapp-unicorn）

```
upstream myapp.com {
    #my rails app
    server unix:/var/www/rails/myapp/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock      fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com;
    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size 35M;
        proxy_pass http://myapp.com;
    }
}
```

【unicorn.rb】（/var/www/rails/myapp/config/unicorn.rb）

```
worker_processes 2

listen File.expand_path('tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock', ENV['RAILS_ROOT'])

stderr_path File.expand_path('log/unicorn.log', ENV['RAILS_ROOT'])
stdout_path File.expand_path('log/unicorn.log', ENV['RAILS_ROOT'])

preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    old_pid = "#{ server.config[:pid] }.oldbin"

    unless old_pid == server.pid
        begin
            Process.kill :QUIT, File.read(old_pid).to_i
        rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH

        end
    end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Thank you for your patience with my poor English.

## Add

this is unicorn.log（/var/www/rails/myapp/log/unicorn.log）

```
I, [2015-09-05T18:17:20.590239 #10832]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2015-09-05T18:17:22.099133 #10832]  INFO -- : unlinking existing   socket=/var/www/rails/myapp/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock
I, [2015-09-05T18:17:22.099389 #10832]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/var/www/rails/myapp/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fd=11
I, [2015-09-05T18:17:22.115503 #10832]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2015-09-05T18:17:22.118878 #10836]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2015-09-05T18:17:22.127008 #10839]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
```

this is nginx.log（/var/log/nginx/error.log）

The nginx log is none...

Comment: Share Unicorn and Nginx error logs both

Comment: thank you for your reply! I added logs!

Comment: Nginx error log shouldn't be empty, look for details. It looks like: *connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client ....* need more details from Nginx log. Try to rename upstream, do not make it look like FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

If your error is

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```

Try running unicorn listen on

```
listen /tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock
```

instead of

```
listen File.expand_path('tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock', ENV['RAILS_ROOT'])
```

because some times it happens that nginx can't read that socket file due to permissions. It is rather safe if you have socket file inside **tmp** folder. Also point you **NGINX** to

```
server unix:/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock      fail_timeout=0;
```

instead of

```
server unix:/var/www/rails/myapp/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock      fail_timeout=0;
```

Please reply if you still get  error
Happy Deployment ;)

Comment: This is incorrect answer! Unicorn master itself has been started successfully.

Comment: @Anatoly although unicorn and nginx started successfully mostly connection refused comes when nginx couln't fin the sock file or could not read that sock file .....

Comment: @Anatoly i have wrote ** if this is the error ** after following you comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410967/nginx-and-unicorn-not-working/32416928?noredirect=1#comment52710754_32416928